# Background image should not assume I use a white background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I like to use a grey background for Firefox to ease eye strain while reading plain text. Many sites (including unix.stackexchange.com) assume the browser uses a white background.  This

If you intend the site to have a white background with subtle dots, please adjust the background image accordingly.

[image: how unix.se.com looks to me]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glenn, I have re-created the background pattern image. Instead of using a solid color for the dot(which doesn't play well with darker bgcolor), I have made it  translucent. It should look fine on the gray #ccc you use. This change will be in the next deployment. Be sure to do a hard refresh.